# JodaTime : How do I check if given date falls in a particular Week and then a particular Day and in a particular month?

Tags: java, date, datetime, jodatime

I want to check if a given date falls in 2nd week or 4th week and the day is Sunday for example and that too in a given month say August.
Is it achievable via JodaTime. If yes please explain.

Comment: Your title and your question body are asking different things. Asking "How do I get the Sunday in the second week in August?" is not the same as asking "Can I check if a date *is* the Sunday in the second week in August?" Please show what you've tried, and give details about what you mean by "second week", too, bearing in mind that there are multiple ways of defining that.

Comment: you can get the week count from Calender class, you have to put some manipulation to get what you are looking for

Comment: Jon : I have edited the question Titile... I think now both are in sync

Comment: Basil : I have read that link before posting this question, that is not serving this purpose, but like khan said I guess I have to tweak a little bit to get what I want.

Comment: on the above given link, Frank Monzas answer worked for me